# Python functions and their __call__ attribute

Tags: python

I am using Python 2.7.2.  I want to understand the relationship between calling a function and calling the `__call__` attribute of the function.  For example, consider the following code

```
def foo():
    return 5
print foo()          # ==> 5
print foo.__call__() # ==> 5

foo.__call__ = lambda : 6
print foo()          # ==> 5
print foo.__call__() # ==> 6
```

The firsts four lines seem to indicate the calling the function `foo` is the same as calling the `__call__` attribute of `foo`.  However, the last three lines seem to indicate that they are different beasts since I changed the `__call__` attribute but it didn't change the value returned by a call to `foo()`.

Can someone explain the relationship between calling `foo()` and calling `foo.__call__()`?  Is there a way to modify the behavior of the function so that `foo()` as well as `foo.__call__()` now returns 6 instead of 5?

Comment: There's never a reason to modify `foo.__call__` -- you could just modify `foo` instead!

Comment: nevertheless it is a strange behavior. good question

Answer (score 12):

I recommend you read [special method lookup for new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) (especially the last paragraph).

> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are
> only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not
> in the object’s instance dictionary.

Comment: You should elaborate about how the fact that we're working with a function here doesn't really matter, since functions are objects and there's a class that they belong to (`<type 'function'>`), etc....