# How do I override a method object's __call__ method in Python?

Tags: python

Here is what I am working with so far

```
def f(n):
    return n

f.__call__ = lambda n: n + 1

print f(2) #I expect an output of 3 but get an output of 2
```

I am not interested in another way to achieve the desired output. Rather, for educational purposes, I would like to know why overriding the `__call__` as I have done, doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Try to execute `dir(f)` to see that they have it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707600/python-functions-and-their-call-attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be due to special-casing of function types in [ceval.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/524693d62093/Python/ceval.c#l4040), in `call_function`:

```
if (PyFunction_Check(func))
    x = fast_function(func, pp_stack, n, na, nk);
else
    x = do_call(func, pp_stack, na, nk);
```

I'd guess that this is probably for efficiency, since calling regular functions, and ignoring the `__call__` attribute, is by far the most common kind of calling that gets done.

Comment: I've changed the link to point to hg.python.org since this is the official repository for CPython now.