# Update single-dispatch overload after decorating

Tags: python, python-decorators, single-dispatch

## Preface

I'm using [single dispatching](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-single-dispatch) with [`functools.singledispatch` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) like

```
from functools import singledispatch
from typing import Any


@singledispatch
def serialize(object_: Any) -> str:
    raise TypeError('Serialization for objects '
                    'of type "{type}" is not supported.'
                    .format(type=type(object_)))


@serialize.register(int)
def serialize_int(object_: int) -> str:
    return str(object_)
```

now if I want to conditionally decorate `serialize_int` like

```
log_int_overload = True  # some condition here

if log_int_overload:
    from functools import wraps


    def log(function):
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            result = function(*args, **kwargs)
            print('For {args}, {kwargs} function returned: {result}.'
                  .format(args=args,
                          kwargs=kwargs,
                          result=result))
            return result

        return wrapped


    serialize_int = log(serialize_int)
```

then call

```
>>> serialize(1)
'1'
```

as we can see invokes "old", undecorated version. This happens because we've registered only "old" one overload and `serialize` don't know anything about decorated since it is a new function object.

## Problem

How to modify overloads so "dispatcher"-function will grab changes?

I understand that we can register `serialize_int` again after decorating, but it looks like a code repetition issue, is there any other way?

Or more generally: can we somehow modify function object in-place? Decorating `__call__` attribute [won't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707600/python-functions-and-their-call-attribute).

Comment: You prolly want to decorate with `log` first, then register the decorated version and use your flag to log (or not log) inside the `wrapper` function.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: yes, I can, but it won't work if I want to decorate overload that is not written by me